# window.open() reference is having closed true, after perform submit in child window without closing child in chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, window.open, window.opener

when i open child window and search something in search box and when see the 'child.closed' status giving different results in Firefox and Chrome. Please help to get the same status in both browsers.
Firefox: 'child.closed' returns false
Chrome: 'child.closed' returns true

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Sample page</title>
    <script>
        function openChild() {
            var child = window.open('http://google.com', 'auditor_child_tab', 'location=yes,status=yes,width=1366,height=768');
            const clearTimeout = setInterval(() => {
                if (child && child.closed) {
                    clearInterval(clearTimeout)
                    console.log("THE CHILD WINDOW HAS BEEN CLOSED")
                } else {
                    console.log("OK")
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Sample Page</h1>
    <button onclick="openChild()">Open Child</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.closed property should be giving the same response in both browsers. This is the standard way to check window is still opened. I see one problem in your code. You should also check whether the window object is null or not.

```
function openChild() {
            var child = window.open('http://google.com', 'auditor_child_tab', 'location=yes,status=yes,width=1366,height=768');
            const clearTimeout = setInterval(() => {
                if (child === null || child.closed) {
                    clearInterval(clearTimeout)
                    console.log("THE CHILD WINDOW HAS BEEN CLOSED")
                } else {
                    console.log("OK")
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
```

Regards,
omi

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. In the above code i am not getting any issues with `if (child === null || child.closed) {
                    clearInterval(clearTimeout)
                    console.log("THE CHILD WINDOW HAS BEEN CLOSED")
                } else {
                    console.log("OK")
                }` with this code. the only problem is the child.closed is becoming true with chrome browser only when i  submit form. For example open child window, search something in search box of google page and see the child status. it is giving true in chrome not in firefox